# Is it possible to use custom font in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-text-editor

Gmail only provides these fonts:

- Sans Serif
- Serif
- Comic Sans MS
- Courier New
- Garamound
- Georgia
- Tahoma
- Trebuchet MS
- Verdana

But I don't wanna use any of those. I want to use the font of my own choice, for example: Lucida Grande, or any other fonts.

Is there any tricks or hacks to do that?

Comment: It appears there is a dirty trick. Check [this](http://globolstaff.com/how-to-change-default-gmail-font-and-use-your-wanted-fonts.html) blog entry.

Comment: If you want such a feature added, submit it at the [Gmail Feature Suggestions Page](https://support.google.com/mail/suggestions/16932?rd=1).

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but I believe fonts are held client/operating-system-side and as a result if my mac uses helvetica and a windows users opens the email it will appear as Arial, but then when an android users opens it, it will be android sans serif. I.e. I don't think you can do what you want to do.

Answer (score 4):

Not really, no. I have seen some reports that if you copy-paste from some other app (like Google Docs or Microsoft Word) Gmail will continue to display the font used in the original. It's unclear what happens once you send the message or try to change fonts again.

Basic steps:

1. Enable canned responses
2. Create a canned response by pasting text with your desired font into the editor
3. Save the canned response as normal, naming it with the font you used
4. Use your custom font in an email by simply using the custom tag you want and simply replacing your placeholder text with the text that you want.

Answer (score -1):

1. Open Microsoft Word or any HTML page with the font you like.
2. Write you email with that font.
3. Copy Paste into Gmail Compose window

Not sure if Gmail provides more fonts in the Dropdown, but you can use the above method.

Comment: Recipients see the fonts pasted do they?